# insterstitial ads not showing from google admob after app is published

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, ads

Im using admob to dipslay ads on my game which is published on the play store. During the first 3 days the interstitial ads showed fine but now it just shows a black screen.

[What app shows instead of interstitial ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMk1A.png)

That is what the screen looks like. If you wanna see for yourself the game is delta shooter from delta productions inc

So is this my fault or admobs fault?

Banner ads work fine by the way

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look right.

Suggest you run it past the Admob engineers at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk

But make sure you post your code.